# Is there any Ubuntu 12.04-compatible, open-source 3D modeling software capable of creating a 2D cross-section?

Tags: software-recommendation, cad

I've heard that Blender's boolean algorithm might do the trick, but was wondering if a CAD software had this functionality.  Would want an end result similar to a stratigraphic cross-section.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OpenVSP (Open Vehicle Sketch Pad).  You can slice up your solid and get cross sections. Image is of a Cessna 182 with 21 slices, along with some control panels.[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or example?

Answer (score 0):

Try [FreeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/)

> FreeCAD is a parametric 3D modeler. Parametric modeling allows you to
>   easily modify your design by going back into your model history and
>   changing its parameters. FreeCAD is open source (LGPL license) and
>   completely modular, allowing for very advanced extension and
>   customization.

[image]

For more information, and to download FreeCAD, visit their [website](http://www.freecadweb.org/).

<sup>Source:[FreeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Mitch! This is definitely something I'll try. Have you used FreeCAD before?  And do you know how it compares to an application like LibreCAD or Blender, in terms of performance and capability to handle detail (without crashing)?

Comment: I honestly haven't used it, but this [site](http://opensourceecology.org/wiki/CAD_tools) has a comparison between these products.

Answer (score 0):

alongside softwares in the site that Mitch suggests(http://opensourceecology.org/wiki/CAD_tools), I suggest **MEDUSA4**. it is not opensource but have free personal version.