# CAD (Photoshop, SketchUp, Corel) apps on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am planning to replace Windows, but I'm  worrying if CAD application such as Autodesk AutoCAD, 3ds Max, Corel Draw and SketchUp, are they working well with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Those applications will not run under Ubuntu. You might try with [wine](https://askubuntu.com/q/316025/58950), but do not expect all software running smoothly.

On the other hand, you can try free linux software for [CAD](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090607033315929/CAD.html) and [graphics](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/2008091312364896/Graphics.html). You can also check out this directory [of CAD linux software](http://www.tech-edv.co.at/sl.php?058010).

Check some of the alternatives or recommendations given, for example, in the following Q&A: [How to get Autocad working with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/q/121528/58950), [What good CAD programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/26954/58950), [Is there any Ubuntu 12.04-compatible, open-source 3D modeling software capable of creating a 2D cross-section?](https://askubuntu.com/q/338970/58950).

You can find (probably a lot) more if you do a simple [search in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search).

Answer (score 0):

No CorelDraw in linux (yet). You'll have to live with Inkscape and GIMP. No Autodesk products working in linux, with one exception. Autodesk MAYA runs great in many linuxes. MAYA is pretty close to 3dsMax, perhaps even better. MAYA is famous for Hollywood special effects (LOTR trilogy in particular).